# XSL for-each(-group) nested in for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

We're aiming to print invoice lines grouped first by type of service being invocied and then by job description and constultant names, in this manner:

### CONSULTANCY

**Doing Actual Work**
Gummo - 2014-03-03
Zeppo - 2014-02-24
Harpo - 2014-03-07

**Snide Remarks**
Groucho - 2014-02-24

**Harp Playing**
Harpo - 2014-02-28

### EXPENSES INCURRED

Cigars

We're extracting this data from an xml file with a somewhat complex structure, namely the national Danish OIOUBL standard:

```
<Invoice>

(...)

<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:Note>Bla bla</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="EA">1.2500</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="DKK">1395.0000</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:Delivery>
      <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2014-02-24</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
    </cac:Delivery>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="DKK">348.75</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="DKK">1395.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="DKK">348.75</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
          <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="320" schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:taxcategoryid-1.1">StandardRated</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Percent>25.00</cbc:Percent>
          <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="320" schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:taxschemeid-1.1">63</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Name>Moms</cbc:Name>
          </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
      </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description>Snide Remarks</cbc:Description>
      <cbc:Name>CONSULTANCY</cbc:Name>
      <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo">Groucho</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:ExtendedID>Timer</cbc:ExtendedID>
      </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
      <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo">2014-02-24</cbc:ID>
      </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
      <cac:AdditionalItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo">10000</cbc:ID>
      </cac:AdditionalItemIdentification>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="DKK">1116.0000</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>

(...)

  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>6</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="EA">1.0000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="DKK">1116.0000</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:Delivery>
      <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2014-03-06</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
    </cac:Delivery>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="DKK">279.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="DKK">1116.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="DKK">279.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
          <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="320" schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:taxcategoryid-1.1">StandardRated</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Percent>25.00</cbc:Percent>
          <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="320" schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:taxschemeid-1.1">63</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Name>Moms</cbc:Name>
          </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
      </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description>Cigars</cbc:Description>
      <cbc:Name>EXPENSES INCURRED</cbc:Name>
      <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo"></cbc:ID>
        <cbc:ExtendedID>Timer</cbc:ExtendedID>
      </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
      <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo">2014-03-06</cbc:ID>
      </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
      <cac:AdditionalItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="9" schemeID="foo">20000</cbc:ID>
      </cac:AdditionalItemIdentification>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="DKK">1116.0000</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>

  </Invoice>
```

We start our XSL style sheet off by doing a simple for-each loop which groups invoice lines by cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemIdentification (the consultancy lines are labelled 10000 and the expenses lines are labelled 20000); we then need to ensure that each consultancy line is grouped first by job description (cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cbc:Description). We've tried several iterations of further for-each loops, for-each-group'ing and solutions which used key. However, they all seem to fall back on XPath issues

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$layouttype = '1'">

    <xsl:for-each select="cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemIdentification[cbc:ID='10000']">
        <!-- Invoice headline - Printed once-->
        <xsl:if test="number(position()) = 1">
            <fo:table-row margin-left="0mm" margin-right="0mm" white-space="normal">
                <!-- see if period is empty so colspan should be = 2 -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../cac:StandardItemIdentification/cbc:ID != 'n/a'">
                        <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                            <fo:block margin-bottom="1mm" font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../cbc:Name"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2" display-align="after">
                            <fo:block margin-bottom="1mm" font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../cbc:Name"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- the actual invoice line -->
        <!-- and this is where it gets tricky... -->

        <xsl:for-each-group select="../cbc:Description" group-by="../cbc:Description">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="../cbc:Description"/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>


            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">

                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>

                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../cac:SellersItemIdentification/cbc:ID"/>
                        </fo:block>

                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemIdentification[cbc:ID='20000']">

<!-- then the same pattern is repeated -->
```

Comment: So what is the problem you face? Your code does `for-each-group select="../cbc:DescriptionNested"` but I don't even find an element named `cbc:DescriptionNested` in the input snippet you posted.

Comment: You might want to avoid the for loop. XSLT is first and foremost (pun intended) a pattern matching excercise. I would break that one into 2 steps: step 1: hammer the source XML into an XML format that has the right structure and in step 2: decorate it with FO layout.

Comment: @stwissel: Unfortunately, the XML format cannot be changed as it's a government standard. Or do you mean to take the relevant data and put into some sort of temporary xml file or array that the data could then subsequently be extracted from?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: you're correct - cbc:DescriptionNested must have been some sort of copy/paste error - it should have been cvc:Description and I've corrected the post above accordingly.

Comment: Hi Lars, the second option is what I meant. Transform the fixed government format into something that contains what you need in the right order and feed that into XSL:FO with a second stylesheet that does the FO decorating. You wouldn't need to write the temp format out (after everything works, during development the intermediate format makes a nice debugging entry point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to avoid repeated code where you can. It is not clear if you are only ever going to have "Consultancy" and "Expenses Incurred", but it may be safe to assume not. I am also going to assume you can have multiple **Item** elements per **InvoiceLine** (although the solution given still work if this is not the case).

Anyway, you would start off by grouping **Item** elements by their **AdditionalItemIdentification**. This would create your groups for "Consultancy" and "Expenses Incurred"

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item" 
                    group-by="cac:AdditionalItemIdentification/cbc:ID">
```

Then, the title of each group would done by simply outputting the name

```
<xsl:value-of select="cbc:Name" />
```

Now, within the current group (of **Item**) elements, you then need to group by **description**

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" 
                    group-by="cbc:Description">
```

Finally, in this group (still of **Item**) you want to group by **SellersItemIdentification**, although you probably need an extra check because not all **Item** elements have them (in the case of "Expenses Incurred"

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[cac:SellersItemIdentification/cbc:ID != '']" 
                    group-by="cac:SellersItemIdentification/cbc:ID">
```

Outputing the current "seller" would them be a case of using the grouping-key, and other fields:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
<xsl:value-of select="cac:StandardItemIdentification/cbc:ID" />
```

As I don't know XSL-FO very well, the XSLT provided as an example will just output vague "table" and "row" elements, but it should give you the general idea.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
                xmlns:cac="cac" xmlns:cbc="cbc" exclude-result-prefixes="cac cbc">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Invoice">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item" group-by="cac:AdditionalItemIdentification/cbc:ID">
            <table>
                <row><xsl:value-of select="cbc:Name" /></row>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="cbc:Description">
                    <row><xsl:value-of select="cbc:Description" /></row>

                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[cac:SellersItemIdentification/cbc:ID != '']" group-by="cac:SellersItemIdentification/cbc:ID">
                        <row>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /> - <xsl:value-of select="cac:StandardItemIdentification/cbc:ID" />
                        </row>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>                    
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following (based on your provided sample, which only includes Groucho, and not poor old Zeppo or Harpo)

```
<table>
   <row>CONSULTANCY</row>
   <row>Snide Remarks</row>
   <row>Groucho - 2014-02-24</row>
</table>
<table>
   <row>EXPENSES INCURRED</row>
   <row>Cigars</row>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying to convert Peppol invoices myself and am interested in your script but it does not provide the output that you stated. Am I missing something (it was a long time ago but your xslt knowledge is still fresh enough).